# Istio policy not authenticating JWT

Tags: python, kubernetes, istio

I have implemented an istio policy so that users will need a JWT token to access my backend, and admin-backend services. However, it is not letting me through with a valid token. I am running istio-demo on minikube and have done nothing with my deployment but configure an egress for auth0. Then when I go to apply my policy, I can no longer access these services with my requests.

rbac-policy.yaml

```
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: rbac
  namespace: default
spec:
  targets:
    - name: backend
    - name: admin-backend
  peers:
    - mtls: {}
  origins:
    - jwt:
        issuer: "https://jor2.eu.auth0.com/"
        jwksUri: "https://jor2.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

This is what is being passed in my get and post request headers(value of HEADERS):

```
{
  "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik5VVkdPREl4UVRoQlFrWTJOakV4UWpnek1FSkVNalZCUVRjM1FUaEJOVFk0UVRZM016aEVNQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2pvcjIuZXUuYXV0aDAuY29tLyIsInN1YiI6IlRsdmg5OFl4Wkc2anFpNmRVclhlN2RIejVwZzFiaHR1QGNsaWVudHMiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL3JiYS5jb20vYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1NTI1NTU0NjUsImV4cCI6MTU1MjY0MTg2NSwiYXpwIjoiVGx2aDk4WXhaRzZqcWk2ZFVyWGU3ZEh6NXBnMWJodHUiLCJzY29wZSI6IkFkbWluIiwiZ3R5IjoiY2xpZW50LWNyZWRlbnRpYWxzIn0.grrHHrS_Ey63Tmo1KL9gUmelouYaSj0rPlv04tpJxBeVct-KRA30I1ieVgncmojRBXcdgvfpWKjeGLbb2Q7X6QwkdT0LyO3jmOBgabcTIsnnbCEg4gywc7WrN5_H_bWNiToIsouagJqiAOQ35wrVa9SVK_InR0QVEnV3yvuug042yMiMmFriG6qN2J8HPgXCE440hpSXBIIKuoBqmNZGSjZV3YvQXaLmigCNl2_PUXb52urrQqHEh06dMIT2FFfD5Cdc1RGrRT2o4krMWF2mJMOWXK1sgEOv4FfsOrdkPka24MuGViED514EoJ9a2n2QEK10zxDtv42opYT9Wjmubg"
}
```

function with correct header(should work) but doesn't display any responses.

```
@app.route("/view_patients/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_patients():
    global HEADERS
    patients = invoke_backend(page_name="view_patients", headers=HEADERS)
    return render_template(
        'view_patients.html',
        patients=patients
    )
```

Test to make sure token fails on invalid jwt:

```
@app.route("/test/view_patients/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_view_patients_invalid_jwt():
    jwt = "1nv4l1DJwT"
    header = {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + jwt
    }
    patients = invoke_backend(page_name="view_patients", headers=header)
    return render_template(
        'view_patients.html',
        patients=patients
    )
```

[proxy logs](https://pastebin.com/swqzu89E)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out a few days ago and forgot to post the answer. I needed to remove mtls from config.

```
apiVersion: authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: auth-policy
spec:
  targets:
    - name: backend
    - name: admin-backend
  origins:
    - jwt:
        issuer: "https://jor2.eu.auth0.com/"
        jwksUri: "https://jor2.eu.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

Comment: i have the same configuration as urs, i have an app with spring security oauth2, onc i configured the other app Policy, it is just ignored, i can call the api's without token, could you please share ur project ?

Comment: once i set a Role Based Access Control, get 503, i followed ur config about egress and roles etc, in case i got 503 , my repo github.com/jamesmedice/Istio-Rbac-Policy-Mesh if u can check to have an idea what's missing or is wrong i appreciate , tks ,  OBS: my oauth2 security is on local machine